# Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string (occurs inside in the where clause)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I tried to resolve the error for the below code but don't know how to do this.

In the where condition I checked the concat strings which are returning the date in string formats but the error occurs somewhere in the conversion.

Can someone please let me know where and how to resolve this issue.

Hint: `ERSConstructedVariable_ExecutionDate` is a `datetime` datatype in the table.

`@OutputTimeDimensionvalue` = '1989 - 1998'

Code:

```
SELECT 
    Column1, column2, column3
FROM  
    Table1 CV
WHERE 
    CV.ERSConstructedVariable_ExecutionDate 
       BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime2, CONCAT(substring(@OutputTimeDimensionvalue, 1, 4), '-01', '-01'))  
           AND CONVERT(datetime2,CONCAT((substring (@OutputTimeDimensionvalue, 7, 4)), '-01', '-01'))
```

Comment: Don't ever use `CONVERT` against a date without a conversion number. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx pick the correct format and use it. If you remove the `-` delimiters altogether you can use format 112. Note that `datetime2` also has a time component. Perhaps datatype `date` would be better?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid . . . Although I agree that conversion numbers are a good idea, SQL Server has built-in formats that are readily converted *independent of other settings*.  So ANSI standard formats such as YYYYMMDD (and under almost all circumstances YYYY-MM-DD) are readily supported, as is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the second year starts at position 8 rather than 7.  However, try `left()` and `right()` instead:

```
SELECT Column1, column2, column3
FROM Table1 CV
WHERE CV.ERSConstructedVariable_ExecutionDate BETWEEN
          CONVERT(datetime2, CONCAT(LEFT(@OutputTimeDimensionvalue, 4), '-01-01'))  AND 
          CONVERT(datetime2, CONCAT(RIGHT(@OutputTimeDimensionvalue, 4), '-01-01'))
```

Comment: @GowthamRamamoorthy A little observation, the end date range of the `ExecutionDate` may be 12-31 instead of 01-01

Comment: Again.. don't ever use `CONVERT` with dates without a conversion number.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever use CONVERT against a date without a conversion number

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Given that `@OutputTimeDimensionvalue = '1989 - 1998'` I suggest the following code:

```
SELECT Column1,column2,column3
FROM  Table1 CV
WHERE 
CV.ERSConstructedVariable_ExecutionDate 
BETWEEN CONVERT(
   datetime2, 
   CONCAT(substring(@OutputTimeDimensionvalue,1,4),'0101'),
   112
)  AND 
CONVERT(
   datetime2,
   CONCAT((substring (@OutputTimeDimensionvalue,8,4)),'0101'),
   112
)
```